# How do I gain access to a server if it has no ports open?

Tags: linux, root, nmap

I know the IP address and the root password of a server running Linux, but it has no network ports opened. I can ping it and it responds. How do I gain access to it?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the system?

Comment: you ask the system administrator nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no network services available to connect to a server, then you cannot connect to it over the network.

Alternative approaches

- Use a physical console or, if you are not local to the machine, have someone else log on to the physical console. Perhaps the systems administrator or the someone from the hosting company if it's hosted.
- If the server is a virtual machine you may be able to log on to the console remotely using IPMI or another similar technology.